# Keyboard shortcut to cycle through member types in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense

In later versions of VS (2017 for me), intellisense offers a grouping by member type (property, method, extension method, etc).  Is there a keyboard shortcut to cycle through these so that I don't have to use the mouse to click the tabs?

[image]

Comment: Hi, search around and there have no the official document to list the shortcuts for those types, like Frank said, we can know the shortcut while move the mouse on those types.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, What about this issue? Would you please share the latest information in your side?

Answer (score 0):

Hover your cursor over the relevant icon to get a tooltip that tells you the keyboard shortcut...

[image]

Comment: Just getting back to this. I was hoping for the ability to cycle/tab through them, but will accept this as answer if it's the only way. Can't seem to locate these shortcuts in the settings, either. Any idea what they're named?